# How to do a Stack of unique_ptr

Tags: c++11, containers

Imagine you have a stack of `unique_ptr` to something (an int to simplify), like:

```
std::stack< std::unique_ptr<int> > numbers;
numbers.push( std::unique_ptr<int>( new int(42)) );
```

But if you try to use the top element, without getting it from the stack, you will get an compile error:

```
if( not numbers.empty() ){
    auto lastone = numbers.top();
    std::cout << "last " << *lastone << std::endl;
}
```

You should move out the element, use it, and then put again in the stack:

```
if( not numbers.empty() ){
    auto lastone = std::move(numbers.top());
    numbers.pop();
    std::cout << "last " << *lastone << std::endl;
    numbers.push( std::move(lastone) );
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your second code is wrong; you should `pop` not `top`. To fix the first sample, use a reference.

Comment: @Dave [`std::stack::pop`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) returns `void`, you have to use `top` first.

Comment: @syam so it does. I missed that it was being called on the next line. So, yes, the code is fine. The fix to the first one is still references (which I see your answer suggests too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't intend to actually pop the element but just want to use it inplace, just use a reference:

```
auto& lastone = numbers.top();
std::cout << "last " << *lastone << std::endl;
```

Comment: Or use `*numbers.top()` directly.